# How to optimise gridview on item click method?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-gridview

I'm working on a project where gridview is used for selecting items, everything works fine, but there is this other problem; workflow just feels clumsy, like when you try to click on item, GV slides a bit and click is not registered, now or then you have to click twice to register click. How to achieve responsiveness?

Are there any guidelines for optimising such situations or any alternate more reliable way?

```
public class CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

    public CustomGridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                                 ArrayList<Item> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.linearLayout=(LinearLayout)row.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutGridViewItem);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewGridItemName);
            holder.imageItem = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewGridItemIcon);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        final Item item = data.get(position);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getNaziv());


        byte[] image= new byte[0];
        try {
            image = Base64.decode(item.getArti_image().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            holder.imageItem.setImageBitmap(
                    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length)
            );
            //Log.v("test",image+"");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //holder.imageItem.setImageDrawable(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //

            }
        });
        return row;

    }


}
static class ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView imageItem;

}
```

Comment: post code.............

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: Code posted, i think my code is fine, overall behavior is clumsy.

Comment: Implement `onItemClickListener` method for `GridView` instead of `row.setOnClickListener`.